# IoTEdge on K8S, Could not initialize module runtime

Tags: azure-iot-edge

I'm running iotedge on kubernetes.

The K8S cluster is a local cluster setup largely using the "Kubernetes the hard way" method, with some modifications.

I did manage to get things working on one installation.  However, I'm now getting this on another installation.  The initial installation works fine, but after shutting down a machine to simulate a hardware failure, the pod gets recreated, but starts to show this error again.  This error happens EVEN if the node shutdown is NOT the one iotedged is running on.

**Environment**

- 3 Nodes running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
- Two networks on each node, one for the internet, one for an internal network.  K8S is setup using the internal, static IP address
- HAProxy/Keepalived for HA without a load balancer, running on a Virtual IP address
- Multus CNI for attaching pods to additional networks
- CoreDNS

**Troubleshooting**

- Confirmed that CoreDNS seems to be functioning fine, and is able to resolve internal and external addresses
- Remaining nodes are able to ping pods on other nodes
- Deleting the iotedged pod and allowing k8s to recreate it works, but then edgeAgent an edgeHub have errors until I delete/recreate them as well
- Re-run the entire k8s installation.  Initial installation works fine, but simulating machine failure continues to be problematic.

**Kubernetes Versions:**

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"21", GitVersion:"v1.21.0", GitCommit:"cb303e613a121a29364f75cc67d3d580833a7479", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-04-08T16:31:21Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.1", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"21", GitVersion:"v1.21.0", GitCommit:"cb303e613a121a29364f75cc67d3d580833a7479", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-04-08T16:25:06Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.1", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

**edgeiotd error:**

```
<6>2021-07-09T22:00:02Z [INFO] - Starting Azure IoT Edge Security Daemon - Kubernetes mode
<6>2021-07-09T22:00:02Z [INFO] - Version - 1.1.3
<6>2021-07-09T22:00:02Z [INFO] - Using config file: /etc/iotedged/config.yaml
<6>2021-07-09T22:00:02Z [INFO] - Configuring /var/lib/iotedge as the home directory.
<6>2021-07-09T22:00:02Z [INFO] - Configuring certificates...
<6>2021-07-09T22:00:02Z [INFO] - Transparent gateway certificates not found, operating in quick start mode...
<6>2021-07-09T22:00:02Z [INFO] - Finished configuring provisioning environment variables and certificates.
<6>2021-07-09T22:00:02Z [INFO] - Initializing hsm...
<6>2021-07-09T22:00:02Z [INFO] - Finished initializing hsm.
<6>2021-07-09T22:00:02Z [INFO] - Provisioning edge device...
<6>2021-07-09T22:00:02Z [INFO] - Starting provisioning edge device via manual mode using a device connection string...
<6>2021-07-09T22:00:02Z [INFO] - Manually provisioning device "********" in hub "********.azure-devices.net"
<6>2021-07-09T22:00:02Z [INFO] - Finished provisioning edge device.
<6>2021-07-09T22:00:02Z [INFO] - Initializing the module runtime...
<6>2021-07-09T22:00:02Z [INFO] - Attempting to use config from /home/edgeletuser/.kube/config file.
<6>2021-07-09T22:00:02Z [INFO] - Using in-cluster config
<3>2021-07-09T22:00:34Z [ERR!] - The daemon could not start up successfully: Could not initialize module runtime
<3>2021-07-09T22:00:34Z [ERR!] -        caused by: Could not initialize kubernetes module runtime
<3>2021-07-09T22:00:34Z [ERR!] -        caused by: HTTP response error: SelfSubjectAccessReviewCreate
<3>2021-07-09T22:00:34Z [ERR!] -        caused by: Hyper HTTP error
<3>2021-07-09T22:00:34Z [ERR!] -        caused by: error trying to connect: Connection timed out (os error 110)
<6>2021-07-09T22:00:02Z [INFO] (/project/hsm-sys/azure-iot-hsm-c/src/hsm_log.c:log_init:41) Initialized logging
```

**edgeHub Logs after recreating iotedged:**

```
2021-08-18 19:05:40  Starting Edge Hub
2021-08-18 19:05:40.481 +00:00 Edge Hub Main()
<7> 2021-08-18 19:05:40.609 +00:00 [DBG] [Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Util.Edged.WorkloadClient] - Making a Http call to http://localhost:35001/ to CreateServerCertificateAsync
<7> 2021-08-18 19:05:40.912 +00:00 [DBG] [Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Util.Edged.WorkloadClient] - Error when getting an Http response from http://localhost:35001/ for CreateServerCertificateAsync
HTTP Response:

{"message":"Module not found"}

Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Util.Edged.Version_2019_01_30.GeneratedCode.IoTEdgedException`1[Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Util.Edged.Version_2019_01_30.GeneratedCode.ErrorResponse]: Not Found
   at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Util.Edged.Version_2019_01_30.GeneratedCode.HttpWorkloadClient.CreateServerCertificateAsync(String api_version, String name, String genid, ServerCertificateRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /home/vsts/work/1/s/edge-util/src/Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Util/edged/version_2019_01_30/generatedCode/HttpWorkloadClient.cs:line 624
   at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Util.TaskEx.TimeoutAfter[T](Task`1 task, TimeSpan timeout) in /home/vsts/work/1/s/edge-util/src/Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Util/TaskEx.cs:line 126
   at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Util.Edged.WorkloadClientVersioned.Execute[T](Func`1 func, String operation) in /home/vsts/work/1/s/edge-util/src/Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Util/edged/WorkloadClientVersioned.cs:line 59
Unhandled exception. System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Error calling CreateServerCertificateAsync: Module not found)
 ---> Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Util.Edged.WorkloadCommunicationException- Message:Error calling CreateServerCertificateAsync: Module not found, StatusCode:404, at:   at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Util.Edged.Version_2019_01_30.WorkloadClient.HandleException(Exception ex, String operation) in /home/vsts/work/1/s/edge-util/src/Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Util/edged/version_2019_01_30/WorkloadClient.cs:line 109
   at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Util.Edged.WorkloadClientVersioned.Execute[T](Func`1 func, String operation) in /home/vsts/work/1/s/edge-util/src/Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Util/edged/WorkloadClientVersioned.cs:line 77
   at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Util.Edged.Version_2019_01_30.WorkloadClient.CreateServerCertificateAsync(String hostname, DateTime expiration) in /home/vsts/work/1/s/edge-util/src/Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Util/edged/version_2019_01_30/WorkloadClient.cs:line 35
   at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Util.CertificateHelper.GetServerCertificatesFromEdgelet(Uri workloadUri, String workloadApiVersion, String workloadClientApiVersion, String moduleId, String moduleGenerationId, String edgeHubHostname, DateTime expiration) in /home/vsts/work/1/s/edge-util/src/Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Util/CertificateHelper.cs:line 260
   at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Hub.Service.EdgeHubCertificates.LoadAsync(IConfigurationRoot configuration, ILogger logger) in /home/vsts/work/1/s/edge-hub/src/Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Hub.Service/EdgeHubCertificates.cs:line 54
   at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Hub.Service.Program.MainAsync(IConfigurationRoot configuration) in /home/vsts/work/1/s/edge-hub/src/Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Hub.Service/Program.cs:line 54
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
   at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Hub.Service.Program.Main() in /home/vsts/work/1/s/edge-hub/src/Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Hub.Service/Program.cs:line 33
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you still blocked? what troubleshooting steps you have tried so far? Did you check the [Common issues and resolutions for Azure IoT Edge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/troubleshoot-common-errors?view=iotedge-2020-11)? As per the error messages **Transparent gateway certificates not found, operating in quick start mode** and **The daemon could not start up successfully: Could not initialize module runtime** looks like the setup is not configured properly. Try restarting the server and check the transparent gateway setup. Please refer the [transparent gateway setup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/iotedge-gateway-on-kubernetes/iot-edge-workloads-on-kubernetes/) and check if you have missed anything.

Comment: Hi Ashok, I've added some more information in an edit at the bottom.  I did solve the problem once, but it's come up on another installation, but with slightly different characteristics.  This installation should have a direct connection to the internet - do I still need to have a transparent gateway in this case?  I didn't think it was necessary?